# Android - What is a Handler Message?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I'm talking about [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html).

The main documentation states:

> Defines a message containing a description and arbitrary data object
>   that can be sent to a Handler. This object contains two extra int
>   fields and an extra object field that allow you to not do allocations
>   in many cases.

- So I would assume that it is some kind of communication between
  different threads, maybe a `Bundle`?
- There are also a [few snippets](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) in the main documentation. But I
  can't see how are they built and what is their structure.
- Why to use them instead of using `SharedPreferences` or maybe a `Singleton` class? Testing?

---

I would love to see a little and compact example on when and how to use them.

Comment: It makes sense when you learn about Handlers also, since that's how the Message class is useful

Comment: I have used Handlers also already, I do know that they have their own handleMessage() method, but I haven't gotten the need to really use Messages yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I would assume that it is some kind of communication between different threads

You can attach a `Handler` to the main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread), and you can create separate `HandlerThread` instances for other threads with associated `Handler` instances.

One thread can send a `Message`, via a `Handler`, where the `Handler` will process the `Message` on its own thread, in the `handleMessage()` method. For example, a regular background `Thread` could package the results of its work (e.g., downloaded data) into a `Message`, and give that to a `Handler` attached to the main application thread. That `Handler` will get the `Message` in `handleMessage()`, called on the main application thread, and can then update the UI safely using the data from the background thread.

This is a *very* low-level means of inter-thread communication in Android. More often, you are better served using something a bit higher-order, like an event bus.

> Why to use them instead of using SharedPreferences

`SharedPreferences` are for data storage, not inter-thread communication.

> or maybe a Singleton class?

While a singleton can provide a central point of data, on its own, it does not provide any sort of inter-thread communication.

> I would love to see a little and compact example on when and how to use them.

For 99% of Android developers, the answer is: don't use them. Use something that is built on top of `Handler` and `Message`, such as:

- `AsyncTask`
- `LocalBroadcastManager`
- Square's Otto
- greenrobot's EventBus
- etc.

Comment: Thanks! What problem would have to have the other 1% in order to actually use it?

Comment: @Evin1_: They are the people who write things like `AsyncTask`, `LocalBroadcastManager`, Otto, etc. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Thread can have one handler and one messageQueue only, a message is some arbitrary data that is handled by the handler whom put on it's messageQueue, the messageQueue loop every message and process them until it has no more message, all data are versatile and executed asap, no need to save it on HDD, it's low level code you dont deal with it often